# how to save value from HTML id for comparing in for loop

Tags: html, meteor

I want to compare two values in a for loop, already tried using #tmpid.val ,not working.

```
<template name="productpendingstatus">

       {{#each totaltemplate}}

       <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">

        <thead><tr><td colspan="3">{{this.META.TEMPLATE_NAME}}</td>

<td id="tmpid">{{this._id}}</td> <want to compare this value in code below>

</tr></thead>
        </table>
        <div class="pendingProducts">
          <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">

            <tbody>


                {{#each productt}}
                {{#if $eq <value of id tmpid> this.TemplateID.value }}//this is ques

                <tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                  <td>{{this.ProductId.value}}</td>

                </tr> 
                {{/if}}
                {{/each}}


            </tbody>

          </table>
       </div>
       {{/each}}



    </template>
```

Comment: Which template framework are you using? Please add it as a tag to your question.

Comment: your `id="tmpid"` is rendering multiple time with your loop. the static `id` is not making seance. there may be a one or more templates create same ID multiple time on HTML page

Comment: yes I will do the comparsion in each loop, you can change it to dynamic also, no problem

Comment: @OhAuth didnt get you..are you asking for package used for comparsion?

Comment: @garima This question is tagged HTML yet it is not straight HTML and doesn't actually question the HTML. Please tag the framework which uses the curly brace blocks seen in your example. It will help users with a knowledge of the framework find your question.

Comment: ok. I am using meteor application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference a parent data context in a template, Spacebars now provide [the "../" notation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#name-resolution):

```
<template name="productpendingstatus">
       {{#each totaltemplate}}
       <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
        <thead><tr><td colspan="3">{{this.META.TEMPLATE_NAME}}</td>
<td id="tmpid">{{this._id}}</td> <want to compare this value in code below>
</tr></thead>
        </table>
        <div class="pendingProducts">
          <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
            <tbody>
                {{#each productt}}
                {{#if $eq ../_id this.TemplateID.value }}
                <tr>
                  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                  <td>{{this.ProductId.value}}</td>
                </tr> 
                {{/if}}
                {{/each}}
            </tbody>
          </table>
       </div>
       {{/each}}
    </template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper to get the parent data

```
<template name="productpendingstatus">
{{#each totaltemplate}}
<table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr><td colspan="3">{{this.META.TEMPLATE_NAME}}</td>
    <td id="tmpid">{{this._id}}</td> 
    </tr></thead>
</table>
<div class="pendingProducts">
  <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      {{#each productt}}
      {{#if isPending }}
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
        <td>{{this.ProductId.value}}</td>
      </tr> 
      {{/if}}
      {{/each}}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

and then on js file

```
 Template.productpendingstatus.helpers({
  isPending: function(){
    var parentData = Template.parentData();
    return parentData._id === this.TemplateID.value;
  }
});
```